# How to Capture All Metrics with IMetricsConsumer?

Tags: apache-storm

I have created an implementation of `IMetricsConsumer` and registered it in my topology via YAML as follows. Any custom metrics that I have created in my own code do get successfully passed to this consumer.

```
  topology.metrics.consumer.register:
    - class: "hnb.storm.metric.opentsdb.OpenTsdbMetricConsumer"
      parallelism.hint: ${storm.topology.metrics.consumer.parallelism}
```

Unfortunately, other 'external' metrics created outside of my code never get passed to this consumer.  For example, I am using a `storm.kafka.KafkaSpout` that creates its own metric called `kafkaOffset` using the same API.  My consumer never receives this metric.

How do I ensure that my consumer receives 'external' metrics like `kafkaOffset`?

Comment: I am not sure, but do you need to include those classes into your `jar` file?

Comment: any luck @Nick Allen ?